# Mapreduce split input string into output array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, split, mapreduce

I am dealing with documents like the following one:

```
> db.productData.find({"upc" : "XXX"}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("538dfa3d44e19b2bcf590a77"),
    "upc" : "XXX",
    "productDescription" : "bla foo bar bla bla fooX barY",
    "productSize" : "",
    "ingredients" : "foo; bar; foo1; bar1.",
    "notes" : "bla bla bla"
}
>
```

- I would like to have a document containing, among the fields, a list/array of splitted ingredients (on the `;`). I want to split the string of the original collection into an array of strings.
- I would like to map only some of the input fields in the output collection.
- I would like to use `mapreduce` on MongoDB.

I've tried many different ways moving stuff from the `map` function to the `reduce` function failing to find a proper solution.
From all the attempts I performed, now I know I need to check for `null` values etc, so the following one is my last attempt:

The map function:

```
var mapperProductData = function () {

    var ingredientsSplitted = values.ingredientsString.split(';');

    var objToEmit = {barcode : "", description : "", ingredients : []};

    // checking for null (is this strictly necessary? why?)
    if ( 
            this.hasOwnProperty('ingredients')
         && this.hasOwnProperty('productDescription')
         && this.hasOwnProperty('upc')
       ) {
        for (var i = 0; i < ingredientsSplitted.length; i++) {
            // I want to emit a new document only when I have all the splitted strings inside the array
            if (i == ingredientsSplitted.length - 1) {
                 objToEmit.barcode     = this.upc;
                 objToEmit.description = this.productDescription;
                 objToEmit.ingredients = ingredientsSplitted;

                 emit(this.upc, objToEmit);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The reduce function:

```
    var reducerNewMongoCollection = function(key, values) {

    return values;
};
```

The map-reduce call:

```
db.productData.mapReduce(
    mapperProductData,
    reducerNewMongoCollection,
    {
        out : "newMongoCollection" ,
        query: { "values" : {$exists: true} }
    }
);
```

I am getting an empty collection in output (`newMongoCollection` is empty).
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start from the beginning. Your map function should look like this:

```
var mapperProductData = function () {    
    var ingredientsSplitted = this.ingredients.split(';');    
    var objToEmit = {
        barcode : this.upc, 
        description : this.productDescription, 
        ingredients : ingredientsSplitted
    };

    emit(this.upc, objToEmit);        
};
```

Your map-reduce call should be:

```
db.productData.mapReduce(
    mapperProductData,
    reducerNewMongoCollection,
    {
        out : "newMongoCollection", 
        query : { 
            upc : { $exists : true }, 
            productDescription : { $exists : true }, 
            ingredients : { $exists : true , $type : 4 }
        } 
    }
);
```

The query part will filter the documents that do have relevant fields. Also the query parameter `$type` will match only documents where ingredients is an array. This way you don't need to do complicated checking inside your map function and the number of documents sent to `map` function will be lower.

The result for your test document document will look like this:

```
key : XXX, 
value: {
    "barcode" : "XXX",
    "description" : "bla foo bar bla bla fooX barY",
    "ingredients" : [
        "foo",
        " bar",
        " foo1",
        " bar1."
    ]
}
```